Using Power Automate to delete files within nested folders in a sharepoint folder
Stuck on apply to each 3
I cannot for the life of me figure out why this flow is not working. I am trying to delete any files within the folders I have selected that are 45 days or more old. The process seems to be getting hung up on the first apply to each after the filter array. There are sub 1,000 files but more than 500 currently.
I have tried to build this without an array, with a condition, and with created instead of modified. It seems to get hung up after filtering every time. I am hoping to make this delete the bulk of the files and then just maintain the numerous folders it checks.

So show us something, too hard to help right now.

Apologies, I thought I had included a screenshot. It is linked in the post now.

Can you clarify what you mean by it’s getting “hung up”? Getting an error of any kind?

There is no error, it just spins on the section that states apply to each 3. I let it run for an entire evening and still had no error and was not complete.

I have included a picture of what I am talking about above.

My tip, change the settings on the loops to only perform a few iterations before it stops. That will help you determine what’s going wrong. Sometimes, if it’s retrying due to errors, it will takes AGES because the retry policy makes it so. So look at the retry policy on the delete file step as well and maybe set it to none. See if that helps.

I got this error after adjusting the settings.
ExpressionEvaluationFailed. The execution of template action 'Foreach' failed: the result of the evaluation of 'foreach' expression '@{outputs('Filter_array')}' is of type 'String'. The result must be a valid array.

But that has nothing to do with the changes I suggested making.
